# Thread Safety Testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, thread-safety

I currently use googles' gtest to write my unit tests, but it doesn't look like it can test thread-safety (that is, accessing something from multiple threads and ensuring it behaves according to spec).

What do you use to test thread safety? I'd like something cross-platform, but, it definitely has to work on Windows atleast.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm no MT expert, but I don't think you can automate MT design testing, the whole thing is rather non-deterministic.

Comment: It should be possible to check certain "contracts", though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing approach for multi-threaded software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437763/testing-approach-for-multi-threaded-software)

Comment: Note that testing MT software is a really hard problem in general. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059895/are-there-any-automated-unit-testing-frameworks-for-testing-an-in-house-threading and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035890/unit-testing-concurrent-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multithreaded code isn't immediately, obviously, provably correct then it is almost certainly wrong. And if it is, you don't need to test it.

Seriously: shared mutable state should be extremely localised and rare, and the classes that do it should be demonstrably correct.

Your threads should normally interact via safe primitives (eg a thread-safe work queue). If you have lots of data structures scattered around your code each with its own locking strategy then your code almost certainly contains deadlocks and race conditions. A big testing effort will only find some of the problems.